# Hide Custom Button in visualforce based on Pemission Sets

Tags: visualforce, button, custom

I Have a visualforce page where I'm having two buttons which I'm hiding to particular profiles based on profile name

```
rendered="{!IF($Profile.Name == 'Profile1'||$Profile.Name =='Profile2'||$Profile.Name =='Profile3', true,false)}"
```

Now i want to hide button for profiles and permission sets(some permission sets i need to show the button), any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a custom apex controller, you can just query the permission set assigned to the current user and do the verification. From there, you can choose to render the buttons or not.

```
List<PermissionSetAssignment> lstUserPermissionSet = [SELECT Id, PermissionSet.Name, AssigneeId                                                              
                                                     FROM PermissionSetAssignment 
                                                     WHERE AssigneeId = :Userinfo.getUserId() ];
```

Variable PermissionSet.Name will give you the name of the permission  set.

Comment: Hi Kevan, Thanks for the prompt reply, as you suggested i have queried and getting the results of the permission set, but i have to show the button to user only with particular profile names or particular permission set. How to render permission set value on rendered. Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use the apex code `UserInfo.getProfileId()` to retrieve the profile id for the current user and from there, do a soql query to get the profile name. Do your logic in the controller side and assigned a boolean value to a variable which will be used to render the button. Hope this help.